# Scala distribution of lists with condition

Tags: scala, list, recursion, combinations

So, it's very straigh forward, I have a list with nested lists, like so:

```
List(
*list1* List(List("n1", "n3"), List("n1", "n4"), List("n3", "n4")), 
*list2* List(List("n2"), List("n3"), List("n4"))
)
```

And I want to destribute the lists of the *list1* with the lists of the *list2*, like so:

```
List(
List(List(n1, n3), List(n2)), 
List(List(n1, n4), List(n2)), 
List(List(n3, n4), List(n2)), 
List(List(n1, n3), List(n3)), 
List(List(n1, n4), List(n3)), 
List(List(n3, n4), List(n3)), 
List(List(n1, n3), List(n4)), 
List(List(n1, n4), List(n4)), 
List(List(n3, n4), List(n4))
)
```

This can be accomplished with the following function:

```
def combinationList[T](ls:List[List[T]]):List[List[T]] = ls match {
  case Nil => Nil::Nil
  case head :: tail => val rec = combinationList[T](tail)
    rec.flatMap(r => head.map(t => t::r))
}
```

The thing is, I want to add a condition where I only destribute lists where there are no duplicates, so the result would be:

```
List(
List(List(n1, n3), List(n2)), 
List(List(n1, n4), List(n2)), 
List(List(n3, n4), List(n2)),  
List(List(n1, n4), List(n3)),  
List(List(n1, n3), List(n4)), 
)
```

The closest I've got is by adding a *filter* and a *contains* before the mapping, but I still can't get the result, like so:

```
def combinationList[T](ls:List[List[T]]):List[List[T]] = ls match {
  case Nil => Nil::Nil
  case head :: tail => val rec = combinationList[T](tail)
    rec.flatMap(r => head.filter(x => !r.contains(x)).map(t => t::r))
}
```

The problem is that I think it's comparing the list as a whole and not the individual elements. Any ideas?

EDIT: I need to ignore duplicates within the function. I know it's possible to post-process the information and remove the ones with duplicates, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to decompose one level further to check the item existence, in a simplest form it can be as follow:

```
def combinationList[T](ls:List[List[List[T]]]) : List[List[List[T]]] = ls match {
    case head :: tail :: Nil =>
      for {
        hl <- head
        tl <- tail
        if !tl.forall(te => hl.contains(te))
      } yield List(hl, tl)
  }
```

It works on the assumption of input list having 2 sublists. I'm not sure what is the expectation of having 3 or more sublists in generic manner, it's all up to you to recursive further.

Comment: Your function receives a *List[List[List[T]]* but that's not what mine receives, so it doesn't work even for my example.

Comment: Your input is definitely a `List[List[List[T]]]`. It should be clear: either it's two if `List[List[T]]` or a `List[List[List[T]]]`. After all, demonstrated code is about ideas.

Comment: I changed a bit and I got it to work. Based on your solution, so I'll mark as answered. If you wanna know, the "!" should be before the *hl.contains(te)* and not where you put it. Regardless, your solution pretty much solved my issue, thanks a lot!

Comment: I have an exception now.
If my input is something like *List(List(List(n1), List(n3), List(n4)), List(List(n2), List(n3), List(n4)))* it works fine, but if it is just *List(List(List(n1), List(n3), List(n4)))* it doesn't work, it gives a Match Error exception. Any ideas?

Comment: Meanwhile I solved it by adding an extra case:
*case head :: Nil  => for(x <- head) yield List(x)*

Answer (score 0):

With the current return type you'd probably have to match again to "look into" the list. Something like might do the job:

```
def combinationList[T](ls:List[List[T]]):List[List[T]] = ls match {
    case Nil => Nil::Nil
    case head :: tail => val rec = combinationList[T](tail)
        rec.flatMap(r => head.filter {
            case xx: List[_] => {
                val combined = (xx.map(List(_)) ++ r)
                combined.distinct == combined
        }
  }.map(t => t::r))
}
```